# Symfony2 - Looking for entity class in wrong place?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have two entities, User and Lesson.

User is an extension of the Sonata User and is in

```
Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Lesson is in my own bundle 'LessonBundle'

Each lesson is owned by a user, under the field tutor:

```
class Lesson
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="lessons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tutor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tutor;

/**
     * Set tutor
     *
     * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $tutor
     * @return Lesson
     */
    public function setTutor(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $tutor = null)
    {
        $this->tutor = $tutor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tutor
     *
     * @return \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getTutor()
    {
        return $this->tutor;
    }
}
```

I have a form set up which successfully adds a lesson for a user, however when I try to access the list of lessons:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('LessonBundle:Lesson');

//Problem is triggered here
$lessons = $repository->findAll();
```

I get the following error:

```
Class LessonBundle\Entity\User does not exist
```

> Stack Trace
>
> ```
> in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
> ```
>
> at line 233  -+
>                               }
>                               // We need to pick the type hint class too
>                               if (($paramClass = $param->getClass()) !== null) {
>                                   $parameterString .= '\' . $paramClass->getName() . ' ';
>                               } else if ($param->isArray()) {
>                                   $parameterString .= 'array ';
>       at ReflectionParameter ->getClass ()
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
>   at line 233  -+
>       at ProxyFactory ->_generateMethods (object(ClassMetadata))
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
>   at line 155  -+
>       at ProxyFactory ->*generateProxyClass (object(ClassMetadata), '/home/dan/sites/mysite/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/**CG***_LessonBundleEntitySubject.php',
>   '; /** * THIS CLASS WAS GENERATED BY THE
>   DOCTRINE ORM. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. */ class  extends
>   \ implements \Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy { private
>   $_entityPersister; private $*identifier; public $*_isInitialized =
>   false; public function **construct($entityPersister, $identifier) {
>   $this->_entityPersister = $entityPersister; $this->_identifier =
>   $identifier; } /** @private */ public function _*load() { if
>   (!$this->*_isInitialized** && $this->_entityPersister) {
>   $this->**isInitialized** = true; if (method_exists($this, "**wakeup"))
>   { // call this after _*isInitialized*_to avoid infinite recursion //
>   but before loading to emulate what ClassMetadata::newInstance() //
>   provides. $this->__wakeup(); } if
>   ($this->_entityPersister->load($this->_identifier, $this) === null) {
>   throw new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException(); }
>   unset($this->_entityPersister, $this->_identifier); } } /** @private
>   */ public function _*isInitialized() { return $this->*_isInitialized**; }  public function **sleep() {
>    } public function _*clone() { if
>   (!$this->*_isInitialized** && $this->_entityPersister) {
>   $this->**isInitialized** = true; $class =
>   $this->_entityPersister->getClassMetadata(); $original =
>   $this->_entityPersister->load($this->_identifier); if ($original ===
>   null) { throw new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException(); } foreach
>   ($class->reflFields as $field => $reflProperty) {
>   $reflProperty->setValue($this, $reflProperty->getValue($original)); }
>   unset($this->_entityPersister, $this->_identifier); }  }
>   }')
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
>   at line 90  -+
>       at ProxyFactory ->getProxy ('LessonBundle\Entity\Subject', array('id' => '1'))
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   at line 2576  -+
>       at UnitOfWork ->createEntity ('LessonBundle\Entity\Lesson', array('id' => '1', 'date' => object(DateTime), 'time' =>
>   object(DateTime), 'objective' => 'test', 'created_at' =>
>   object(DateTime), 'updated_at' => object(DateTime), 'tutor_id' => '1',
>   'service_id' => '1', 'trip_id' => '1', 'subject_id' => '1',
>   'location_id' => '1'), array('deferEagerLoads' => true, 'fetchMode' =>
>   array('LessonBundle\Entity\Lesson' => array('tutor' => '2', 'service'
>   => '2', 'trip' => '2', 'subject' => '2'))))
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php
>   at line 135  -+
>       at SimpleObjectHydrator ->hydrateRowData (array('id1' => '1', 'date2' => '2013-02-09', 'time3' => '00:00:00', 'objective4' =>
>   'test', 'created_at5' => '2013-02-09 12:19:27', 'updated_at6' =>
>   '2013-02-09 12:19:27', 'tutor_id7' => '1', 'service_id8' => '1',
>   'trip_id9' => '1', 'subject_id10' => '1', 'location_id11' => '1'),
>   array('id1' => array('class' => object(ClassMetadata), 'name' => 'id',
>   'field' => true), 'date2' => array('class' => object(ClassMetadata),
>   'name' => 'date', 'field' => true), 'time3' => array('class' =>
>   object(ClassMetadata), 'name' => 'time', 'field' => true),
>   'objective4' => array('class' => object(ClassMetadata), 'name' =>
>   'objective', 'field' => true), 'created_at5' => array('class' =>
>   object(ClassMetadata), 'name' => 'created_at', 'field' => true),
>   'updated_at6' => array('class' => object(ClassMetadata), 'name' =>
>   'updated_at', 'field' => true), 'tutor_id7' => array('name' =>
>   'tutor_id'), 'service_id8' => array('name' => 'service_id'),
>   'trip_id9' => array('name' => 'trip_id'), 'subject_id10' =>
>   array(*DEEP NESTED ARRAY*), 'location_id11' => array(*DEEP NESTED
>   ARRAY*)), array())
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php
>   at line 50  -+
>       at SimpleObjectHydrator ->hydrateAllData ()
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php
>   at line 111  -+
>       at AbstractHydrator ->hydrateAll (object(PDOStatement), object(ResultSetMapping), array('deferEagerLoads' => true))
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   at line 848  -+
>       at BasicEntityPersister ->loadAll (array(), null, null, null)
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php
>   at line 157  -+
>       at EntityRepository ->findBy (array())
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php
>   at line 141  -+
>       at EntityRepository ->findAll ()
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/src/LessonBundle/Controller/LessonController.php
>   at line 21  -+
>       at LessonController ->listAction ()
>       at call_user_func_array (array(object(LessonController), 'listAction'), array())
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1426  -+
>       at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1390  -+
>       at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1566  -+
>       at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 617  -+
>       at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
>       in /home/dan/sites/mysite/web/app_dev.php at line 29  -+

I'm not sure why it's looking for the User class in the LessonBundle rather than Application\Sonata\UserBundle.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  There was a reference to the class in the wrong location in a completely different class!